# Python Docstring: What do these docstring parameters mean exactly?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, pydoc

Can someone tell me the differences between the following docstring parameters?

`:type` and `:param`
I've seen both being used to specify the type of method arguments, but I don't think they do exactly the same. Is one of them for the programmer and the other for the IDE or something like that?

`:rtype`, `:return` and `:returns`
Especially :return and :returns seem very similar, so which are to use in which situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These conventions are used by the Sphinx documentation tool, which was originally designed for processing Python docs. Its popularity has, however, led it to be extended into other domains, defined in [the Sphinx documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html) as "a collection of markup (reStructuredText directives and roles) to describe and link to objects belonging together".

According to the linked page `:return` comes from the Python domain, `:returns` from the JavaScript domain, and they both appear to be used for the same thing (*i.e.* documenting the return value of a function or method). In practice `:returns` appears so infrequently one wonders whether it's a documentation typo.

`:rtype` specifies the return type, and will create a link to the type definition if that's possible (*i.e.* if Sphinx can find the definition in the code you are documenting).

Answer (score 1):

None of them mean anything by themselves. Various programs will scan a docstring and interpret certain pieces (or *tags*) specially for formatting, linking, etc. By convention (starting with `javadoc`?), such tags often begin with `:`. Beyond that, the specific meaning depends on the program parsing the docstring, and there is no defined standard for what tags should be used. Some programs use `:return` to document the return value of a function, others use `:rtype`.

The only real answer to your question is, consult the documentation for the program you expect to process your docstrings.